# using mod_tile in windows

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, osm2pgsql, apache, mod-tile

I am trying to generate tiles on the fly in windows using mod_tile. I have followed the tutorial http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/ on ubuntu and successfully got it running but I want to do the same in windows. Could anyone help me by sketching up a tutorial for the above.

Answer (score 2):

You might try Maperitve as a lightweigt source of rendering tiles as well.

It works on Windows on small and medium areas, and needs no database.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. How about using tirex and node js instead of mod_tile and renderd? Does it workk in windows??

Comment: I have no tried those. With Mapnik, I have pre-rendered my tiles with generate_tiles.py.

Comment: Thanks again. I am actually trying to set up a locally hosted map server and build map tiles on the fly. The requirements are: 1. The server must be bound for windows. 2. The rendering must be done using a javscript library called Leaflet. 3. The loading,copying and moving operations of the map tile must be quicker.

Comment: I have already tried TileStache with POSTGIS. If you have done setting up your own tile server in windows, can you send me some step by step instructions?

Comment: I just used generate_tiles.py to render the tiles I want once, and access them via a local Apache server with http://localhost to a shared directory. I guess that does not fit your needs. BTW, delivering pre-rendered tiles is faster than on-the-fly-rendering.

Answer (score 1):

[mod_tile](https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile) effectively has no Windows support. If you don't need it's cache invalidation, you might consider a tile server like [MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/) which has [Windows support](http://mapproxy.org/docs/1.7.0/install_windows.html) and can render a Mapnik-based map. You'll find that there is relatively little to no documentation about getting all of the parts to work together on Windows systems.

If you do get it working, Windows is not recommended for large databases so you may find additional limitations there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. How about using tirex and node js instead of mod_tile and renderd? Does it workk in windows??

Comment: Tirex works with mod_tile, it's a replacement for renderd. NodeJS is a language. There are some tile serving components in NodeJS, but I don't have experience with them and they are not widely used.