# Create a Map Tile Server in Windows

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, tiles, tile-server

I need a Tile Server to use in another application (Traccar) that will work on a Windows machine without a network.
However, I saw that to make this work I would need a Tiled Map and a Tile Server. As I don't have any experience with anything like this, I looked for tutorials that could help me, but I couldn't.
After several attempts I decided to look for help.

Note: I used QGIS to generate the Tiles, but the format generated is OSM, and apparently it is not necessary to use on the Tile Server.

So, could anyone recommend a tutorial or a way to make this happen?

Edit: Traccar needs the link in the format like this `http://domain.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` or `http://domain.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}`.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. This is a problem-solving site. For tutorials you can search google. So you can only ask for the solution of the problem.

Comment: But I have a problem, and a big one. As I said in the notes, I even managed to create it, but when I generated the file in QGIS it returned the file in OSM format and I need it to return something like this: http://domain.com/tiles/{z}/{x }/{y}.

Comment: And I tried to Google it too, but I found it all very confusing. What I achieved was creating an Apache server to host the Map Tiles.

Comment: Re the "I used QGIS to generate the Tiles" comment - I'm guessing that something went wrong.  I've not used it but https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14087/generating-map-tiles-with-qgis#331326 suggests it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need raster map tiles in a format such as [http://domain.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](http://domain.com/tiles/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png) then the "least amount of work" answer is probably either:

- Using [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) and in there installing a minimal Debian or Ubuntu and then following [this guide](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-debian-12/).
- Using Docker and then following [this](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/using-a-docker-container/).

You'll then want to use [render_list](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/renderd/render_list.1.en.html) or something that calls it like [render_list_geo](https://github.com/alx77/render_list_geo.pl) to create an initial set of tiles to show.

Once you've got an "initial set of tiles" you can use a native Windows webserver to serve them (or possibly even the filesystem; if Traccar uses something like [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) internally then it will support this.

The challenges with this approach include:

- Lots of small files might use lots of disk space or other resources (inodes etc.)
- You'll need to make sure that whatever's in the VM or Docker is "self-maintaining" and doesn't eventually fill whatever container it is in.

Despite being 7 years old, the answers [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130474/using-mod-tile-in-windows) are also worth a look at.